# Trasferring binary files through PHP

Tags: php

[if you can find a better title for this question, please fix]

I got an unlimited shared hosting plan [unlimited storage+bandwidth] where i wanna create a virtual online mp3 library. But the problem is the restriction from the hosting provider is

## at most 40% of bandwidth can be mp3 or image files

So how to fool the provider so we can allow users to download the files.

I'll use PHP

Comment: Depends how they scan the traffic, if they are scanning the binary fingerprint for mp3/image. Then I think the only way is encryption for those streams.

Answer (score 1):

Archive them as ZIP or RAR files.

Answer (score 0):

You could rename them to another extension and then change the mimetype to make that extension work like an mp3 or image file.

However, I'd look for a new host.  If you want to create an mp3 library, you should choose a provider that doesn't restrict this.

Comment: Could you elaborate the firlst line of your answer, As i've already invested money so i'm not planning to move to other now :(